# What does a ".number" following a function name mean in LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

In LLVM IR, **a "." and a number** following a function name.

Such as

```
@kmalloc.2670，@kmalloc.19
```

What does this number mean?

It is often the situation that **a same function name followed by different numbers.** However, the definition code of the two functions are the **same**.

Can anybody help me?

```
define internal i8* @kmalloc.2670(i64 %size, i32 %flags) #5 !dbg !436635
define internal i8* @kmalloc.19(i64 %size, i32 %flags) #5 !dbg !1202009
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this right?
LLVM docs:

> One nice thing about LLVM is that the name is just a hint. For
>   instance, if the code above emits multiple “addtmp” variables, LLVM
>   will automatically provide each one with **an increasing, unique numeric**
>   **suffix**. Local value names for instructions are purely optional, but it
>   makes it much easier to read the IR dumps.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It is only used for annotation purposes.

Comment: I am wondering why Clang compiler defines one function (such as kmalloc above) many times?

Comment: Can you share a c-code example where LLVM is behaving in such a way? One thing that I notice is that both functional defines have different metadata nodes attached (i.e.  !436635 and !1202009). This might be the reason why you see these similar defines